# Recursion - Printing the wrong amount of attempts

Tags: java, recursion, passwords, combinations

So given 5 digit password, the maximum attempts it takes to crack the password should be 62^5 but I am getting a 3 digit number (62*5). What should I change?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;

class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Letters for the random generated password
    // Variables
    String letters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890";
    Random order = new Random();
    int PASSWORD = letters.length();
    // While statement to allow user to keep generating passwords
    while (true) {
        String password = "";
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        // Print/menu
        System.out.println("Press 1 to generate a random password");
        // Takes user input
        int UserOption = input.nextInt();

        // If user input equals 1
        if (UserOption == 1) {
            // Generate a 5-character passwords from the letters in the String
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                password = password + letters.charAt(order.nextInt(PASSWORD));
            }
            System.out.println(password);
            cracking(5, password, letters, 0, "");
        }
        // If user input is anything except 1
        else {
            // Print error
            System.out.println("Error");
        }
    }
}

//Recursive Method
private static int cracking(int length, String password, String characters, int tries, String tryPass) {
    System.out.println(length);
    //Base case
    if (length == 0) {
        return 0;
    }
    //Recursive Base
    for (int i = 0; i < characters.length(); i++) {
        if (password.charAt(length-1) == characters.charAt(i)) {
            tryPass = characters.charAt(i) + tryPass;
            break;
        }
        tries++;
    }
     System.out.println("It took " +  tries + " tries to crack the password");
    cracking((length-1), password, characters, tries, tryPass);
    return 0;
}
}
```

---

Result

Press 1 to generate a random password

1

AFNTK

5

It took 36 tries to crack the password

4

It took 81 tries to crack the password

3

It took 120 tries to crack the password

2

It took 125 tries to crack the password

1

It took 151 tries to crack the password

0

Answer (score 1):

Because you are guessing every character one by one, so it takes fewer attempts. You should try building one complete guess of 5 characters and then try to guess the entire password with it, if it doesn't work then you try again with another complete guess of 5 characters.

Comment: That makes more sense! What should I change so that it guess 5 characters together instead of each character by itself?

Comment: Well, it requires a pretty big refactor of the cracking method, but basically start with a String of "aaaaa", compare it, and then replace the first letter with the next one in the list, so it ends as "aaaab", then "aaaac" .... "aaaba", "aaabb", and so on.